# Married in Cyprus

Tags: united-kingdom

Hello I am unsure of the rules regarding bring my wife in to the uk.
My wife is from Nepal and has been working in Cyprus for 16 months.
I am British and in full time work here. 
I would like to know what visa or work permit I need to get?

We have been told we need to change her permit in Cyprus as we are now married but not easy to find out how to do it in Cyprus. They keep talking about pink and yellow slips, I don't know what they mean either.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how long you have been living in Cyprus, you may be eligible to bring your wife to the UK under European Union rules instead of under British law.  This is much less expensive (the [EEA Family Permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit) is free of charge, while a "join your partner or spouse" visa [costs £1,195](https://www.gov.uk/join-family-in-uk)) and requires less paperwork (you don't have to show a certain level of income, for example).

When a British citizen brings family to the UK under EU rules, it's called the *Surinder Singh route.*  You can read more about it on the [UK Government's web site](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit/surinder-singh).

If you haven't been in Cyprus for very long, though, or if you haven't been married for very long, you may have difficulty qualifying under the Surinder Singh ruling.  In that case, you could either work at overcoming those difficulties or, if they seem particularly burdensome to overcome, just [apply under the UK legislation](https://www.gov.uk/join-family-in-uk).

A brief internet search suggests that a pink slip is, in Cyprus, a residence permit for a non-EU citizen, while the yellow slip is the resident card for a EU citizens and their family.  Presumably, your wife has a pink slip now, but has become eligible for a yellow slip by marrying you.  Changing your wife's permit in Cyprus is unlikely to be relevant to your bringing her to the UK, however; it's just about obtaining documents to show her new status in Cypriot and European law.

In other words, before she married you, her permission to be in Cyprus depended (I presume) on her employment.  Now, instead, she has a *right* to be in Cyprus as the wife of an EU citizen (you).  This is obviously a stronger position.

There are other benefits to documenting her new status.  For example, if you remain in Cyprus, and if she gets the so-called "article 10" residence card of a family member of an EU citizen, she would be able to travel with you to the UK (and to any other EU country) without needing a visa.  (The "pink slip" most likely serves as the article 10 card.)  Since the EEA family permit is free, that's not necessarily a huge benefit, but it could be if you plan to travel a lot around the EU over a period of several years.

If you plan to move to the UK relatively soon, it may not be worthwhile to go through the process of obtaining the family member card for Cyprus, though; you could just get the EEA family permit and move to the UK.